How can I fetch all 19 pages of my API instead of just the first within the code I already wrote?
Only the first page of my API is fetched in my current code, and I know I should loop it over the amount of pages to fetch all the data from every page separately, but I have no idea how to integrate it into the code I have currently. I'm very scared of ruining the code I already wrote, so if anyone knows an easy way to meld this into my current code, that would help a lot!
This is what I have now:
import Bird from "./Bird.js";

let map;
let layer;
let point;
let birdList = [];
let filteredBirdList = [];
let clickTimeout = null;
const clickDelay = 300;

function init() {
    fetch(`https://xeno-canto.org/api/2/recordings?query=cnt:belgium`)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (json) {
            //console.log(json.recordings);
            json.recordings.forEach(function (recording) {
                const bird = new Bird(recording.date, recording.lat, recording.lng, recording.en, recording.file);
                //console.log(birdInstance);
                birdList.push(bird);
                //console.log(birdList);
                render(bird.HTMLstring);
            });
        })
        .then(function () {
            sorting();
            searching();
        });

    map = new maptalks.Map("map", {
        center: [4.400528, 50.499861],
        zoom: 8,
        baseLayer: new maptalks.TileLayer("base", {
            urlTemplate: "http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            subdomains: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.osm.org/copyright">OSM</a> contributors, ' + '&copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
        }),
    });

    layer = new maptalks.VectorLayer("vector").addTo(map);
}

//FUNCTIES VOOR SORTEREN/FILTEREN

function sorting() {
    const nameButton = document.getElementById("sortByName");
    const dateButton = document.getElementById("sortByDate");
    nameButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.querySelector("#allBirds-list").innerHTML = "";
        birdList.sort(function (birdOne, birdTwo) {
            if (birdOne.name > birdTwo.name) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        });
        birdList.forEach(function (bird) {
            render(bird.HTMLstring);
        });
    });

    dateButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.querySelector("#allBirds-list").innerHTML = "";
        birdList.sort(function (birdOne, birdTwo) {
            if (birdOne.date > birdTwo.date) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        });
        birdList.forEach(function (bird) {
            render(bird.HTMLstring);
        });
    });
}

function searching() {
    const field = document.getElementById("inputField");
    field.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
        const input = event.target.value;

        filteredBirdList = birdList.filter(function (bird) {
            if (input == bird.name) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        document.querySelector("#allBirds-list").innerHTML = "";

        filteredBirdList.forEach(function (bird) {
            render(bird.HTMLstring);
        });

        console.log(filteredBirdList);
    });
}

//FUNCTIES VOOR DE KAART

function addMarker(lat, lng, name) {
    console.log("pin");
    point = new maptalks.Marker([lng, lat], {
        visible: true,
        editable: true,
        cursor: "pointer",
        draggable: false,
        dragShadow: false, // display a shadow during dragging
        drawOnAxis: null, // force dragging stick on a axis, can be: x, y
        symbol: {
            textFaceName: "sans-serif",
            textName: name,
            textFill: "#34495e",
            textHorizontalAlignment: "right",
            textSize: 13,
        },
    });

    point.addTo(layer);
}

//FUNCTIES VOOR DE SELECTIE ACTIE

window.clicking = function (name, rec, lat, lng) {
    if (clickTimeout !== null) {
        clearTimeout(clickTimeout);
        clickTimeout = null;
        doubleClick(name, rec, lat, lng);
    } else {
        clickTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            singleClick(rec);
            clickTimeout = null;
        }, clickDelay);
    }
};

function singleClick(rec) {
    console.log("enkel");
    playRecording(rec);
}

function doubleClick(name, rec, lat, lng) {
    console.log("dubbel");
    document.querySelector("#myGarden-list").innerHTML += `<button> ${name} </button> </br>`;
    playOnRepeat(rec);
    addMarker(lat, lng, name);
}

//FUNCTIES VOOR HET AFSPELEN VAN HET GELUID

window.playOnRepeat = function (audioFile) {
    const audio = new Audio(audioFile);
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.play();
};

window.playRecording = function (audioFile) {
    //console.log(audioFile);
    const audio = new Audio(audioFile);
    audio.play();
};

//FUNCTIES VOOR HET WEERGEVEN VAN DE KNOPPEN

function render(content) {
    document.querySelector("#allBirds-list").innerHTML += content;
}

init();



It seems you are between two solutions: 1) The one in the title asks to fetch pages 1-19 in a single JSON answer. Since I can see no parameter in the URL you are reaching, it is not parametrized, so that would have to be corrected in your API, that is, the script on the server-side, if you have access to it. 2) By the text you wrote, "i should loop it over the amount of pages to fetch all the data from every page seperately", you might be asking for a client-side solution. Please clarify, and indicate the URLs where you would reach pages 2-19.

@Congregator Hi! Thanks for your reply! I've figured out the URL for the other pages is the same but with &page=number attached, like this https://xeno-canto.org/api/2/recordings?query=cnt:belgium&page=2. It's for a school project, so it's not really for clients but I just want ALL the data instead of just the first page to work with in my project! Hope this helps!

The normal approach is that you have no idea how many pages you have before you start asking, and the results you get include two values that indicate the total number of result sets, and which result set this is, where you perform an initial fetch, and schedule a new fetch every time you get a result for "the next set".

Also, if you're scared of ruining your code, you're not using version control and that should be the very first thing you now do: install git, run git init in the top directory for your project, and start committing changes regularly so you can both look at what things were in the past, and roll back to that code if necessary. And note that "use git" is not the same as "use github" or "use gitlab", git doesn't need those to do its job. Start using version control, because being afraid of losing working code is a low effort, solved problem.

You can use Promise.all to fetch several pages simultaneously:


async function fetchPages(length){
  return Promise.all(Array.from({length}, (_, i) => fetch(`https://xeno-canto.org/api/2/recordings?query=cnt:belgium&page=${i+1}`)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })));
 
}

async function init(){

  const pages = await fetchPages(3);
  for(const page of pages){
    console.log(Object.keys(page));
  }

}

init();




Thanks a lot for the quick reply Alexander!! I'll try this!

Please note that, in current implementation, fetchPages() will return exactly 3 pages, since it is hardcoded. This could be changed to fetchPages(19) to fetch exactly 19 pages. A more versatile version, moreover, should check how many pages there are, and fetch the correct amount.

@Congregator it's just a template to start with, yes, the URLs should be customized and the number of pages
